# Implementing Dropbox in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have added the sdk files like dropbox website says, but I can't figure out how to implement the package. In Xcode, for iOS, the implementation would be done in this way:

```
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>
```

...but in android i can't understand how to do it (I'm new to android). I tried this:

```
package com.dropbox;
```

...and even this...

```
package com.dropbox.android.sample;
```

...from the DBRoulette, but no way: it gives an error saying I have to move the .json file in the lib folder. when I do it, the error disappears, but the app does not launch.

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Your question is very confusion. If you ask sth. about Android please don't write anything about iOS. Also try to clearly formulate what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your project libs folder you need to add the jar file

```
dropbox-android-sdk-1.3.jar
```

and in your project you need to add 
add the import function where you want dropbox.jar class files like below

```
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AccessTokenPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.Session.AccessType;
```

**Note:** your package may be anything you can have it but you need to import package as `com.dropbox....`